# Remove all query results that have duplicates (NOT DISTINCT)

Tags: mysql, count, duplicates, unique, distinct

I have a table with two sets of integer values. Using MySQL I want to display all of the rows that correspond to unique entries in the second column. Basically I can have duplicate A values, but only unique B values. If there are duplicates for a value in B, remove all the results with that value. If I use `DISTINCT` I will still get one of those duplicates which I do not want. I also want to avoid using `COUNT()`. Here's an example:

```
|_A____B_|
| 1    2 |
| 1    3 |
| 2    2 |
| 2    4 |
| 1    4 |
| 5    5 |
```

Will have the following Results (1,3), (5,5). Any value in B that has a duplicate is removed.

Comment: Ricca, check my solution..tested and it workds

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT * FROM TEMP WHERE B IN (
  SELECT B FROM TEMP GROUP BY B Having COUNT(B)=1
 );
```

I know you want to avoid using `COUNT()` but this is the quick solution.

working fiddle here - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/29d16/8

Answer (score 0):

Tested and works! you need atleast count(*) to count the values

```
 select * from test where B in (
   select B from test  group by B  having count(*)<2
 )
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you want to avoid using count(), because that's what would do the trick as follows:

Let's say your table is named "mytable"

```
SELECT t1.A, t1.B
FROM mytable t1
JOIN (
    SELECT B, count(*) AS B_INSTANCES
    FROM mytable
    GROUP BY B
    HAVING count(*) = 1
) t2 ON t2.B = t1.B
ORDER BY t1.A, t1.B
```

Comment: This is a specific requirement for an assignment. The values in the table are also found in other tables and can be queried through those corresponding tables but I was hoping for an easier approach. I will keep trying to find a way then.